# datepicker ui-bootstrap and iso format

Tags: angularjs, date, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I just upgraded from ui-bootstrap 0.13.0 to 0.13.3 and I got a problem with my datepicker directive.

As you can see in this plunkr : [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/toi8qHb1cFVRNxZzzLYY?p=preview)

**example.js**

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
    // datepickers states
    function closeDatePickers(){
        $scope.dtOpened = {
            dt1: false,
        };
    }

    // open date picker
    $scope.openDatePicker = function($event, dpName) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();

        // open one dt at time
        closeDatePickers();
        $scope.dtOpened[dpName] = true;
    };
});
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo')
.directive('datepickerLocaldate', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    /**
     * change model to iso format (yyyy-MM-dd)
     */
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link:  function link(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {

            ngModel.$parsers.push(function toModel(date) {
                if (!date) {
                    return undefined;
                }
                return $filter('date')(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
            });

            var converted = false;
            scope.$watch(function(){
                return ngModel.$modelValue;
            },
            function(modelValue){

                // convert to localDate (remove timezone if necessary), this is for datepicker to synchronize with the good date for negative timezone (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2072)
                if(!converted && modelValue){

                    var dt = new Date(modelValue);
                    if(dt.getTimezoneOffset() > 0)
                        dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + dt.getTimezoneOffset());

                    ngModel.$modelValue = dt;

                    ngModel.$render();

                    converted=true;

                }
            });
        }
    };
}])
.run(['datepickerConfig', 'datepickerPopupConfig', function (datepickerConfig, datepickerPopupConfig) {

    // global settings
    datepickerConfig.showWeeks = false;
    datepickerConfig.startingDay = 1;
    datepickerPopupConfig.showButtonBar = false;

    // when I uncomment next line, everything is working
    datepickerPopupConfig.datepickerPopup = 'dd/MM/yyyy';

}]);
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.3.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

    <style>
      .ng-invalid-date{
        background-color: red;
      }
    </style>

    <div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
      <p>{{'ngModel.$modelValue : ' + search.startDate}}</p>

          <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="date"
                       ng-click="openDatePicker($event, 'dt1')" datepicker-popup datepicker-localdate ng-model="search.startDate" is-open="dtOpened.dt1" required/>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openDatePicker($event, 'dt1')">open dt</button>
                </span>
            </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have a directive (datepickerlocaldate) that convert a date to a localdate and format ngModel in iso format (yyyy-MM-dd).

Everything works fine when I comment :

```
datepickerPopupConfig.datepickerPopup = 'dd/MM/yyyy';
```

But when i uncomment this line (at the bottom of example.js file), if I choose a date nothing is set in ngModel.$modelValue and ngModel is markup as 'ng-invalid-date'.

If I set the input to type="date", this is working but I don't want to do that.

What I am doing wrong? I also reported this as a issue [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4233) to ui-bootstrap team

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I have investigated by making a diff between the 2 files version 0.13.0 Vs 0.13.3 and found that there are a missing code in validate function.

file ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.3.js

```
    function validator(modelValue, viewValue) {
       ...
      // var date = dateParser.parse(value, dateFormat);//Bug line 1752
      var date = dateParser.parse(value, dateFormat) || new Date(value);//Good line fix the problem
      ...
    }
```

The modelValue is formatted as a String, but it is a js Date. The function dateParser.parser() takes the value as a viewValue which is wrong. The viewValue is formatted whereas the modelValue is always a date.

I let ui-bootstrap team tells me if i am wrong

Comment: Yes they removed fallback of string date. Check here : https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4233

Comment: Yes thank you for the link. We are now waiting for the next release